# IE vs Chrome - Image Width / Div Width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This page has a content area where all the posts are held and a side bar. The content and side bar menu are sized properly and fit where they're supposed to in Chrome with the actual posts area taking up the left and the sidebar sitting on the right.

In IE, the images are full-width and I'm not sure of a better way to fix this.

The same issue was occurring where the images were full-width and adding the `width:100%` attribute to the `.htheme_post_image img` element seemed to fix the issue. If you view in IE, the two areas are side-by-side. However, if you click on a post.

The side menu is underneath the post and the images/text are full width.

If it helps, I'm in IE 11.0.9600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed if you remove `display: table;` from both the `.htheme_container` class and the `.htheme_content` class.

This seems to fix your IE issue and has no effect on Chrome, so maybe it's simply not needed. But I did not create this theme, so I have no idea of any side-effects this may cause.